# inserting arrays to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a mysql table where I keep track of members and their friends, and inside that table I have  a field called 'friends'. So if a member frends requests another member the field is updated to both with their respective id's.

For example: if member with id: 125 friends requests member with id: 10 then I insert to the field 10, 125 for member 125 and 125, 10 for member 10. to better explain here is my code.

The problem is that if the user didnt have any previous friends the query still updates the friends field and inserts "Array, 125" instead of inserting "10, 25".

```
$friends = '';

$friendArray = explode(",", $friendArray);
$friendCount = count($friendArray);

if($friendArray != "" && !is_null($friendArray))
{
    $sum = '<h1> '.$friendArray.'\'s friends('.$friendCount.') </h1>';
}
```

But the count variable outputs 1 instead of 0! and that field is NULL.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a bad design to me.  It breaks normal form.  You should not have to parse that column to find out the relationship.

A better solution is to use foreign keys.  A person can have many friends, so build a 1:m relationship into your schema.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this. This isn't a relational DB setup - this is more of a MongoDB type of setup. For MySQL, make a "friends" table and just create data maps.

```
+----+-------------+-------------------+
| ID | User_ID     | Friend_ID         |
+----+-------------+-------------------+
| 1  | 102         | 213               |
| 2  | 64          | 23                |
| 3  | 4           | 344               |
| 4  | 102         | 2                 |
| 5  | 102         | 90                |
| 6  | 64          | 88                |
+----+-------------+-------------------+
```

This assumes it's a mutual friendship. Friend A can't be friends with Friend B if Friend B doesn't want to be friends with Friend A.

Comment: So you mean do that and then select * from friends where user_id = '102' );

Comment: You'd want to search both fields in case someone else added user 102 as a friend and user 102 only accepted the request, but didn't initiate it. That would imply 102 would be in the Friend_ID column. Something like this should work:  `SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(User_ID, Friend_ID) AS user FROM Friends WHERE user = 102`